# IBAction in a container view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller namely DetailViewController in which is embedded a container view controller, IndividualDetailsController.

I would like to know whether is it possible that some change in the DetailViewController could bring about changes in the container view controller i.e, the IndividualDetailsController.

For eg, I would want a button click in the DetailViewController to change a text field value in the IndividualDetailsController controller. Is it possible to do so using IBActions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method

> prepareForSegue

of DetailViewController keep a reference to the embedded one (IndividualDetailsController) in a property of IndividualDetailsController.
Then from an action in DetailViewController you can, for example, change a property of the IndividualDetailsController that can then change its interface accordingly.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MyEmbedSegue"])
    {
        self.individualDetailsController = (IndividualDetailsController*)[segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

then in the action

```
self.individualDetailsController.textFieldValue = newValue
```

Comment: Great, will try this and comment back!